# Dynamic routing in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I want to generate a url like `'top-hotels-in-india'` here `hotels` and `india` is dynamic values that user will search. 
When i am using

`Route::get("top-hotels-in-india",'Controller@method');`

it works, but this is a static url i want this dynamic so changed this into

```
Route::get("top-{things}-in-{country}",'Controller@method');
```

But its not working. If i replace `-` with `/` its works perfect but i want hyphen in url instead of slash.
What should i do to generate this types of routes. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I Never used like this but you can use regex like this,

```
 Route::get("/{dynamic_url}",'Controller@method')->where ("dynamic_url","(top)\-[a-z]+\-(in)\-[a-z]+");
```

If your things and country is known you can also make url by foreach loop.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Remove `/` and try again

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using this kind of URL. But You can try the following route.

```
Route::get("/{dynamic_url}",'Controller@method')->where("dynamic_url","top-[a-zA-z]*-in-[a-zA-Z]*");
```